# Java / JSON class confusion

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I recently started working in Java, coming from a long background in Perl, Ruby, JavaScript, and bash, I am getting a JSON object from a service and want to handle it in Java.

My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
  "stores": {
    "store": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "My Store Name",
        "address": {...},
        "locationNumber": 4567,
        "storeNumber": 890,
        "divisionId": "7",
        "schedule": {...},
        "attributes": {...},
        "features": {...},
        ...
```

I have a service module that returns the JSONArray for stores and I'm able to grab the pieces of the data that I want with expressions such as:

```
storesData.getJSONObject(i).getString("name") + "\n";
```

OR

```
Assert.assertTrue(attributes.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("value").get(0).equals("TRUE"))
```

Now I want to select one store (by name) from the array and return another JSONArray with just that store as the only element in the array. So I coded this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < storesData.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jObj = storesData.get(i);
  ---
```

but it failed saying that storesData.get(i) was not a JSONObject. I had to instead cast the result like so:

```
JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) storesData.get(i);
```

even though in the debugger (IntelliJ-IDEA), this line:

```
storesData.get(i).getClass()
```

reported a class of JSONObject.
**Update for screenshot**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hRsO.png)

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If `storesData.get(i).getClass()` were not equal to `JSONObject` or at least `JSONObject`child class, you would get a ClassCastException during runtime.

Your `storesData` return type is not `JSONObject` but rather ancestor of `JSONObject` or even `Object`. Click on `storesData` in Idea, and go to declaration of variable to see its type.

More examples:

```
class A {
 static Object getInstance() {
     return "invalid object";
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static A getInstance() {
     return new B()
  }
}

B b = B.getInstance();  // compilation error
A a = B.getInstance(); // works
B b = (B) B.getInstance(); // works as well
A a = A.getInstance(); // compilation error
A a = (A) A.getInstance(); // ClassCastException
```

You want to read about [ClassCasting](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html) in java.

Comment: Well; I know about ClassCasting. My questions was why do I have to cast "storesData.get(i)" to JSONObject, when IntelliJ reports that it already is a JSONObject.

Comment: What made you think that Idea thinks that `storesData.get(i)` is a `JSONObject`, show me a print screen.

Comment: Saw results from expression evaluation in IntelliJ; screenshot being posted

Comment: Please read my answer once again. You're facing the situation when `B.getInstance().getClass()` is equal to `B` in your InteJIi Idea. But method returns `A`, that's why you need to `B b = (B) B.getInstance();`